# Python - cv2.groupRectangles returning nothing

Tags: python, opencv

I have my code defined below and my mouth is not null:

```
mouth=mouthCascade.detectMultiScale(roiColor1,1.3, 5)       
rectList, weights = cv2.groupRectangles(np.array(mouth).tolist(), 1, 0.2)
        print rectList
        for (mx,my,mw,mh) in rectList:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (mx,my), (mx+mw, my+mh), (0,45,55), 5)
```

But when I print `rectList` I just get `()()()()()()...`
Can somebody help me please? When I pass mouth as an argument alone? I get an error that's why I've converted it to a list.

Comment: Does it work with the `tolist()`?

Comment: the output of detectMultiScale included the weights. You can try this  `mouth, weight =mouthCascade.detectMultiScale(roiColor1,1.3, 5)`  and change the input for `cv2.groupRectangles` from `np.array(mouth).tolist()` to `mouth.tolist()`